# Filter array property of object without mutating the object itself

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would like to filter a property of an object without mutating the object.

```
let myObject = {
    propA: [1,2,3],
    propB: "foo"
}
```

Now I would like to do something like:

```
myObject.propA.filter(el => el === 2)
```

But this only returns a filtered array and I would have to write

```
myObject.propA = myObject.propA.filter(el => el === 2)
```

in order to change my object.

**But** that's exactly not what I want! I would like to generate a new filtered object without mutating the old one.
Could someone help me out?

Comment: Just clone the object first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `filter()` the array, and then merge it with the original object to create a new one without mutating the original. Something like:

```js
let myObject = {
    propA: [1,2,3],
    propB: "foo"
}
let propA = myObject.propA.filter(el => el === 2)
let newobj = {...myObject, propA}

// new Object
console.log("New:", newobj)

// old object unchanges
console.log("Old:", myObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also clone the object and alter only the property of the new object.

```
let myObject = {
    propA: [1,2,3],
    propB: "foo"
}
let newObject = Object.create(myObject);
newObject.propA = myObject.propA.filter(el=> el ===2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write `transform` using destructuring assignment and spread argument

```js
const transform = ({ a = [], ...rest }) =>
  ({ a: a .filter (el => el === 2)
   , ...rest
   })

const myObject =
  { a: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  , b: "foo"
  }
   
console .log
  ( transform (myObject)
    // { a: [ 2 ], b: "foo" }
    
  , transform ({ a: [ 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 ], b: "bar", c: "cat" })
    // { a: [ 2, 2, 2 ], b: "bar", c: "cat" }
    
  , transform ({ y: "z" })
    // { a: [], y: "z" }
  )
```